# Deploy NodeJS application without git

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to start on Heroku by deploying a NodeJS application I've written.

How do I deploy a NodeJS project to Heroku **without github**, using only the traditional FTP way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can not deploy to Heroku using FTP. Navigate to Heroku's official [deployment documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deployment)

Comment: Then I'd have to host a **private** project on GitHub, which is charged.

Comment: You can use Bitbucket which also uses Git, instead of Github. I think they charge you for private repository if you have 5 or more members in it.

Comment: This logic is not right for me. Having to pay a 3rd party to host a private NodeJS project in Heroku.

Comment: In Bitbucket you don't have to pay anything. You just go, create your profile, then create a private repository completely free and you can use Git features in it.

Comment: Nevertheless, I want to deal with Heroku **only**. I don't want my project going around. This is not actual hosting then.